# How to authenticate with digital ocean container registry using auth token file without dotctl?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, container-registry

I'd like to manually login / authenticate with my container registry.

I've been given a `auth file` that looks like:

```
{"auths":{"registry.digitalocean.com":{"auth":"******************"}}}
```

How do I use this file to authenticate? As `docker login` requires a username and password?

I do **not** want to use the `dotctl` method of authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `docker login` and use the token as **both** username and password

```
docker login -u mytoken -p mytoken registry.digitalocean.com
```

Comment: Source for this? Does not seem to work for me `Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.digitalocean.com/v2/": unauthorized: authentication required`

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode your token before `docker login`.

```bash
echo 'your_token_from_auth_json' | base64 --decode
```

Then use it for docker login